# How can i call my id from my api to reactjs

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, reactjs, web

See Im having a problem im using add in ajax

```
  handleSubmit(name, address,department){

 const laman = {
      'Employee_Name': name,
      'Address': address,
      'Department': department

    }
    return fetch('http://localhost:5118/api/employeedetails/PostEmployeeDetail?', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(laman)
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)

      return response.json();
    })
    .then((result)=> {
       var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
       jsonReturnedValue.push(laman);
       this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
       this.refs.Name.value="";
       this.refs.Address.value="";
       this.refs.Department.value="";
       // this.setState({ value: '' });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);

    })
```

but when it add new row it dont have an id because of it dont know what id to put.... but when i refresh it already had an id because it was added on the database and it was autoincreament in my sql.. id why 
here's a picture[image: here is the image]

Comment: you are returning the response, that will have an id i think.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting this data into `state` variable:

```
const laman = {
   'Employee_Name': name,
   'Address': address,
   'Department': department
 }

var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
jsonReturnedValue.push(laman);
```

Return the data from server and push that data in `state` variable, that will have the id.

Like this:

```
.then((result)=> {     
     var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
     jsonReturnedValue.push(result);
     this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
     .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add an id there like from the previous added value + 1

```
.then((result)=> {
       var jsonReturnedValue = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
       var data = {...laman};
       var length = jsonReturnedValue.length
       data['id'] = jsonReturnedValue[length - 1].id + 1
       jsonReturnedValue.push(data);
       this.setState({jsonReturnedValue})
       this.refs.Name.value="";
       this.refs.Address.value="";
       this.refs.Department.value="";
       // this.setState({ value: '' });
    })
```